# Truncating string down to X amount of characters?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to truncate a string so it only shows the first X amount of characters? Example, you have a string with 600 characters and you only want to display the first 200, how can you truncate the last 400 characters off the string? I have looked at the `.Trim` and `.Remove` functions but it seems `.Trim` only removes white spaces and `.Remote` you need to know how many characters you want to drop, which really does not work for variable length strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use linq methods:

```
var truncated = new string(yourString.Take(200).ToArray());
```

*Take first 200 character from the string put them into an array (char[]) then create a new string using this array*

Or use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var truncated = yourString.Substring(0, 200);
```

*Get the substring starting from index 0 and taking the next 200 character*

Comment: I prefer the substring approach

Comment: I had completely forgotten about `.Substring` thanks.

Comment: Don't use LINQ for that!  You're basically reading X chars, to create an array, and then, again, just to create a string. There is no reason for that waste when `string.SubString` esixts.

Answer (score 1):

With C# 8.0, you can also use a [range indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes):

```
var truncated = yourString[..200];
```

Answer (score 0):

String inherits from `IEnumerable<char>` so:

```
new String(myLongString.Take(200).ToArray());
```

[Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)